# Converter atribuições de C++ para C

Tags: c, c++

Gostaria de ajuda para converter essas atribuições feitas em C++ para C:

```
string binario = bitset<256>(address).to_string();
int InicioDado = 256-log2(cacheconfig.lineSize);
string dado = binario.substr(InicioDado, log2(cacheconfig.lineSize));
int InicioIndex = InicioDado-log2(cacheconfig.numLines/cacheconfig.associativity);
string index = binario.substr(InicioIndex ,log2(cacheconfig.numLines/cacheconfig.associativity));
int InicioTag = 256-cacheconfig.lineSize;
string tag = binario.substr(InicioTag, 256-InicioTag-log2(cacheconfig.lineSize));
long unsigned int Tag = bitset<256>(tag).to_ulong();
long unsigned int Index = bitset<256>(index).to_ulong();
long unsigned int Dado = bitset<256>(dado).to_ulong();
```

Sendo que `adress` é uma variável `unsigned long long int` e as demais são tipo `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Estou supondo que `cacheconfig.numLines`, `cacheconfig.associativity` e `cacheconfig.lineSize` são do tipo `unsigned int`. Se não forem, talvez você vai precisar de um cast em algum lugar, ou então pode mudar elas para serem `unsigned`.

O primeiro passo é arrumar essas subexpressões comuns em um só lugar, e com isso definir as variáveis `a` e `b`:

```
unsigned int a = log2(cacheconfig.numLines / cacheconfig.associativity);
unsigned int b = log2(cacheconfig.lineSize);
string binario = bitset<256>(address).to_string();
int InicioDado = 256 - b;
string dado = binario.substr(InicioDado, b);
int InicioIndex = InicioDado - a;
string index = binario.substr(InicioIndex, a);
int InicioTag = 256 - cacheconfig.lineSize;
string tag = binario.substr(InicioTag, 256 - InicioTag - b);
long unsigned int Tag = bitset<256>(tag).to_ulong();
long unsigned int Index = bitset<256>(index).to_ulong();
long unsigned int Dado = bitset<256>(dado).to_ulong();
```

Vamos eliminar as variáveis do tipo `int` intermediárias:

```
unsigned int a = log2(cacheconfig.numLines / cacheconfig.associativity);
unsigned int b = log2(cacheconfig.lineSize);
string binario = bitset<256>(address).to_string();
string dado = binario.substr(256 - b, b);
string index = binario.substr(256 - b - a, a);
string tag = binario.substr(256 - cacheconfig.lineSize, cacheconfig.lineSize - b);
long unsigned int Tag = bitset<256>(tag).to_ulong();
long unsigned int Index = bitset<256>(index).to_ulong();
long unsigned int Dado = bitset<256>(dado).to_ulong();
```

Agora, vejamos o que isso faz. Você pega o `address`, converte para uma string binária usando o `bitset`, picota essa string em algumas partes e usa o `bitset` para converter essas substrings binárias para números depois. Como isso daí é um cálculo numérico, não me parece ser ideal utilizar strings nele. Isso parece ser uma tarefa para operadores bitwise `<<`, `>>` e `&`.

Primeiro você pega os últimos `b` bits, que são o `Dado`. Os `a` bits anteriores são o `Index`. O `Tag` me parece meio estranho, mas é os últimos `cacheconfig.lineSize` bits com exceção dos últimos `b` bits. Isso é estranho porque há uma intersecção entre o `Tag` e o `Index`.

Bem, para obter os últimos `k` bits de um número `x`, sendo `k >= 1`, podemos fazer isso:

```
x & ((1 << k) - 1)
```

Para descartar-se os últimos `k` dígitos, fazemos isso:

```
x >> k
```

Vamos criar umas macros para deixar mais fácil (acrescentando os parênteses ao redor de cada parâmetro e da macro como um todo para que sejam higiênicas):

```
#define OBTER_ULTIMOS_BITS(x, k) ((x) & ((1 << (k)) - 1))
#define DESCARTAR_ULTIMOS_BITS(x, k) ((x) >> (k))
```

Portanto, o seu código fica assim:

```
unsigned int a = log2(cacheconfig.numLines / cacheconfig.associativity);
unsigned int b = log2(cacheconfig.lineSize);
long unsigned int Tag = DESCARTAR_ULTIMOS_BITS(OBTER_ULTIMOS_BITS(address, cacheconfig.lineSize), b);
long unsigned int Index = DESCARTAR_ULTIMOS_BITS(OBTER_ULTIMOS_BITS(address, b + a), b);
long unsigned int Dado = OBTER_ULTIMOS_BITS(address, b);
```

E esse código é o mesmo tanto em C quanto em C++.

Talvez você ainda vá precisar de uma função que (re)defina o seu `log2`. Aqui segue uma implementação [que copiei dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612244/540552). Só a inclua se você não puder por algum motivo usar a implementação padrão:

```
unsigned int log2(unsigned int x) {
    unsigned int resultado = 0;
    while (x >>= 1) resultado++;
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Realmente, o código compilou sem erros... Porém, o programa não executou... Fiz uma verificação com um printf na variavel a e o problema começa ai... o programa entra em um "loop longo, mas finito" que, obviamente, não retorna o valor final correto. O que pode ser?

Comment: @OberdanSantos Dê alguns exemplos de valores para `address`, `cacheconfig.numLines`, `cacheconfig.associativity` e `cacheconfig.lineSize` que reproduzam esse problema para eu poder testar aqui.

Comment: posso te mandar um email com o .zip dos arquivos?

Comment: @OberdanSantos Pode, mas não vou ter como ver hoje se for mais complicado. De qualquer forma coloquei um [exemplo em C++](http://ideone.com/sIVTB5) e [um exemplo em C com as mudanças que fiz](http://ideone.com/id1Q2O) e os resultados de ambos coincidem. Por isso pedi exemplos de valores para entender o que há de errado.

Comment: passa teu email então,  por favor. Eu precisava disso hoje ainda,  mas tenho certeza que é algo ínfimo que tô deixando passar... vale a Tentativa.

Comment: @OberdanSantos victorwssilva arroba gmail ponto com